# Grails GORM many-to-many relationship

Tags: grails, groovy, orm, grails-orm

I want to delete all the `Tweet`s when its parent `User` is deleted, also delete the collaborators when its parent `Tweet` is deleted. Wherein `collaborators` if of type `User`

Currently, Tweet view doesn't hook up collaborators. I am thinking if I'm doing the following right:

**Tweet.groovy**

```
User owner
static hasMany = [ collaborators : User ]
static belongsTo = User
```

**User.groovy**

```
static hasMany = [ tweet : Tweet ]
```

Comment: trying http://chrisbroadfoot.id.au/2008/07/19/many-to-many-relationship-mapping-with-gorm-grails/

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you lack one relationship that states that a tweet is owned by a particular user. As it is now you will only get a many-to-many relation and I guess you don't want to delete all tweets that a user has collaborated in when you delete a user.

**Tweet.groovy**

```
static hasMany = [ collaborators : User ]
static belongsTo = User
User createdBy
static mappedBy = [collaborators : 'tweet']
```

**User.groovy**

```
static hasMany = [ tweet : Tweet ]
static mappedBy = [tweet : 'collaborators']
```

The mappedBy above is needed since you will have two relationships between the classes and Grails needs to know which one to use for the many-to-many.

Comment: Error: No owner defined between domain classes [class com.brewee.User] and [class com.brewee.Tweet] in a many-to-many relationship. Example: static belongsTo = com.brewee.Tweet

Comment: The accepted answer is the correct syntax but the solution is the same. Go for the accepted answer. I will edit my reply to be correct so that it does not confuse anyone.